# One word: find it from these three lines

Tags: riddle, word

I went to paint in the nature.

Alas, I got a nasty infection.

I did recover by medication.

Comment: Are there any other relevant tags that can be added to help guide the solver?

Comment: I have voted to close this question because it appears likely to invite speculative answers.

Comment: ummm, I am not very well knowledged in possible tags, but...(rot13)rirel yvar pbeerfcbaqf gb n cneg bs n jbeq, yvxr n erohf, so you can help with this if you like

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis You might want to look at the Riley riddle tag.

Comment: @rhsquared There (intentionally) is no Riley riddle tag.

Comment: @Rubio There isn't? I didn't know. Well. The title could be changed. But then again we don't know what was the intended solution and if it matches the 'Riley' pattern.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis, is there a part of the clue that corresponds to the overall solution also. I fear that without that the puzzle is too unclear.

Comment: @rhsquared I entirely fail to see how this matches the Riley pattern - er, I kind of see it now, given the Rot13 comment. Still, the comment should be part of the puzzle IMO.

Comment: @Brandon_J Agreed. $@$GeorgeMenoutis - a "hint" like what you've given in the comments is actually critical information for how your puzzle works, and its lack is probably a big part of why this has been put on hold. Puzzles in general should provide clues to how they should be solved, as part of the puzzle itself, not added as "hints". If the hint is effectively required for anyone not inside your head to solve the puzzle then it's not a "hint", it's an essential part of the puzzle--and in many cases is the only thing preventing your puzzle from being "guess what I'm thinking".

Comment: I suggest you add that important detail to the puzzle and vote to reopen.